# how to avoid collision while paper folding

Tags: rigging, collision

how to avoid collision while paper folding[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add topology, you need at least 2 edges where the topology is supposed to fold:

[image]